# How to make property type depends on it's brother

Tags: typescript, types, casting, type-conversion, typescript-typings

I have configuration that build dynamic components.

Any class implement the property data with some unique type.

I need the `config` property in `ConfType` to have the type of the data within the giving Class in the exec configuration dynamically.

```
type TestData = { /** ...some data object */ }
class TestClass<T extends TestData = TestData>{
  data: T
}
export type ConfType<T extends { data: any }> = {
  type: Type<T>;
  config: T['data'];
}

const dynamicComponentConfig: ConfType = {
  type: TestClass,
  config: will force me to have type of TestClass['data'] // TestData 
  // jsut becuse the type in the brother property is TestClass
  // need to be change dynamically by the Class i Put on the type property
}
```

- the type of the `config` need to be dynamic and depends on the giving class on the property `type`

One way to get it by use function.

I want to get some result without function only types or interfaces

```
// data to be implements
type Data = { fullScreen: boolean }
// class implements data of type data
class Class<T extends Data = Data>{
  data: T
}
// data to be implements
type Data2 = { text: string }
// class implements data of type data
class Class2<T extends Data2 = Data2>{
  data: T
}

// the type of some configuration object
export type ConfType<T extends { data: object } = any, Data extends T['data'] = T['data']> = {
  type: T;
  config: { data: Data };
}
// function that at write the code will play with the giving types // this type will cause that the config type will be depends on the giving class type implements of the data property
const buildConf = function <T extends { data: object }>({ type, config }: Omit<ConfType, 'config'> & { type: Type<T>, config: ConfType<T, T['data']>['config'] }): { type: T, config: T['data'] } {
  return {
    type,
    config // this['type']['data']
  }
}

// build some configuration object
const conf = buildConf({
  type: Class,
  config: { data: { fullScreen: true } } // Class['dta'] === Data
})

// build some wrong configuration object
const conf1 = buildConf({
  type: Class2,
  config: { data: { fullScreen: true } } //  will cause error because Class2['dta'] === Data2
})

// build some configuration object
const conf3 = buildConf({
  type: Class2,
  config: { data: { text: 'my custom text' } } // Class2['dta'] === Data2
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, but you must actually use the generic parameter in `ConfType` in order to enforce the constraint:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UDeUBmBXANrgZQGMAnCCAOwC4oAjAe3twjgqgF8BuAKG6NzgBnQVAAqEQcADCA4QB5RUCAA9glACYj4iFLARwAfOm5Qo6-TVE9TRehUklsRYPRJQAFOcSWAlMdOmwAAWAJaCAHReSKhR1hzc7LwqYK7AUKCQUFJ2mKLgEApKqhoiGFE0rCAcRqhoJun5NBQQAO4e4R1gcCRwALaCFRQgANoAun7IRlb1thSYIQDmlsMA5FErozyJfHaSULPzCwCMNNlzeZAKEtKygjX+DZCW1zJCggA0MzmLNGjs71AAPQAKnqAD0IZD6gAFEj0SAkUBQFY4fDEMiUFZQMJQXphQQhCgLbFsDLQFZ-LG0bBpMgAR2wITI6hJj3J2jgK3C7gATAB2AAsRz8wMBCR4O3saQOix5pxyFwK4kkr2E9zqgUaYhet0+Nm+S3QqMIpHI1HSjgg-3FQA)

```ts
type Data = { fullScreen: boolean };

class TestClass<T extends Data = Data> {
  data: T;
  constructor (data: T) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

export type ConfType<T extends { data: any }> = {
  type: new (...params: any[]) => T;
  config: T['data'];
}

const config1: ConfType<TestClass> = {
  type: TestClass,
  config: {}, /*
  ^^^^^^
  Property 'fullScreen' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Data'.(2741) */
};

// OK:
const config2: ConfType<TestClass> = {
  type: TestClass,
  config: {fullScreen: true},
};
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't give me my goal,
the technic is already working, i can't change it
and i prefer to write the class only in the type because it will be arrayed of dynamic form controls,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This exam, little messy
but this does the job for now

```
type Data = { fullScreen: boolean };
class TestClass<T extends Data = Data> {
  data: T;
}

type Data2 = { fullScreen?: number } & { t: string }

class TestClass2<T extends Data2 = Data2> {
  data: T;
}

class TestClass3<T extends Data2 = Data2> {
}

export enum TableColumnType {
  Test,
  Test2,
}
// 
const dic = {
  [TableColumnType.Test]: TestClass,
  [TableColumnType.Test2]: TestClass2
} as const

type t = { t: string, tt: boolean }

type dataObject<T extends typeof dic = typeof dic> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: {
    type: T[K],
    data?: T[K] extends Type<{ data: infer D }> ? D : never
  }
}[keyof T];

type KeyValuePair<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: { key: K, value: T[K] }
}[keyof T];

type conf<T> = KeyValuePair<T> & dataObject

let tt: conf<t> = {
  type: TestClass2,
  data: { fullScreen: 7, t: '' },
  key: 'tt',
  value: true
}
```

this is the real case perfect type script to build dynamic tables

```
import { DefaultCellComponent } from './default-cell/default-cell.component';
import { LinkCellComponent } from './link-cell/link-cell.component';
import { PriceCellComponent } from './price-cell/price-cell.component';
import { ShareCellComponent } from './share-cell/share-cell.component';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Type } from '@angular/core';
import { ExtendsCellComponent } from './extends-cell/extends-cell.component';
import { tableStyleObj, tableStylesObj } from '../table.component';
import { asConst } from '../../../functions/as-const.func';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

export enum TableColumnType {
    Default,
    Link,
    Price,
    Share,
    Extends,
}

export const TableCellDic = asConst<{ [key in keyof typeof TableColumnType]-?: Type<ITableCell> }>()({
    'Default': DefaultCellComponent,
    'Link': LinkCellComponent,
    'Price': PriceCellComponent,
    'Share': ShareCellComponent,
    'Extends': ExtendsCellComponent,
} as const)

export interface BaseCellData<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T /** will have used on extends components */> { }

export interface ITableCell<T = any, DModel extends BaseCellData<T, K> = BaseCellData<T>, K extends keyof { [key in keyof T]: any } = keyof { [key in keyof T]: any }, V extends T[keyof T] = T[keyof T]> {
    col: ITableColumnObj<T, DModel, K>;
    extends?: EventEmitter<boolean>;
    item: T;
    value?: V;
}

type componentObject<T = any, K extends keyof T = keyof T, D extends { [key in keyof typeof TableColumnType]-?: Type<ITableCell> } = typeof TableCellDic> = {
    [E in keyof D]?: {
        type?: E, //  enum string to tell how is the dynamic component
        data?: (D[E]) extends Type<infer C> ? // when you chose type this will be the data type of this component
        C extends ITableCell<any, infer D, any> ? D : never
        // (C & ITableCell<T, D, K>)['col']['data'] : never
        // & BaseCellData<T,K>
        : never
    }
}[keyof D];

type ITableColumnObj<T = any, DModel = any, K extends keyof { [key in keyof T]: any } = keyof { [key in keyof T]: any }> = {
    field?: K;                                                  // if the table represents data of items like users so 'birthday' is one of the user filed that can display on the table
    label?: string;                                             // th header, the cell header on top of the table
    parsedData?: (val: T[K]) => any;                            // parse the cell data // (date) => moment(date).format('DD.MM.YY')
    parsedFullData?: (item: T) => any                           // get the cell data from the row item // (item)=> item.vatPrice + item.basePrice
    parsedHtmlData?: (val?: T[K], item?: T, parseData?: T[K] | T | any) => Component['template']                     // convert property value to html // exam (val)=> `<div class="someClass">${val}</div>
    styleClass?: string;
    data?: DModel;                                       // cell class like px-10 loading etc.
    style?: { [property: string]: string };                     // cell style object { padding-top: '100px', ... }
    href?: (val: T[K], item?: T) => string | any[] | string[]; // cell href link
    onClick?: (val: T[K], item?: T) => void;                    // on cell click
    colspan?: number;
    hidden?: boolean
    hiddenFunc?: (data: { val?: T[K], item?: T, isHeader?: boolean, items: T[] }) => boolean,
    headerStyleFunc?: (({
        (this: ITableColumnObj<T, DModel>): tableStyleObj;
    })
        | (() => tableStylesObj));
    customClass?: Type<ITableCell<T, DModel, K>>,
}

export type ITableColumn<T extends {} = any, DModel = any> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: Omit<ITableColumnObj<T, DModel, K>, 'data'> & componentObject<T, K>
}[keyof T]

export type getColumnType<T> = T extends ITableColumn<infer T>[] ? T : never

interface User {
    name: string
    age: number
}

let simpleTest: ITableColumn<User>[] =
    [
        {
            'field': 'name',
            type: 'Extends',
            data: {
                title$: of(),
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).